# Rails specify url for resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing an application that has a token resource. The resource will have a standard `create` controller action with the default URI specified by rails, however I wish to alter the `show` and `destroy` actions such that I don't have to supply the id of the token within the URI because it will instead be attained from the request headers.

This is what I have started with:

```
scope module: :auth do
  resources :tokens, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
end
```

This if course yields the following URIs:

```
POST   /tokens(.:format)    
GET    /tokens/:id(.:format)
DELETE /tokens/:id(.:format)
```

But what I want to achieve is:

```
POST   /tokens(.:format)
GET    /tokens/info/(.:format)
DELETE /tokens/revoke/(.:format)
```

and I still want these to map to the controller actions `create`, `show` and `destroy` respectively. Can this be done as succinctly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
resources :tokens, only: [:create] do
  collection do 
    get :info, action: :show
    delete :revoke, action: :destroy
  end
end
```